# Generally speaking, how should one read notation?

Tags: notation, education

I became a better reader when I stopped sub-vocalizing (hearing the words in my head). I still do that when I read math. I tried not to do that when I read an expression today. I felt less confident about it, but it did seem easier. That lead me to suspect there are ways to make notation convenient (currently, it's a hindrance for me).

What are the best practices for reading notation fluently?

Comment: [Somewhat relevant old answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74100/how-can-i-learn-to-read-maths-at-a-university-level/74177#74177)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether or not this applies to you but I find that many students have problems with maths because they don't fully realise that it all *means something*.  Therefore they are trying to solve problems by memorising meaningless strings of symbols, and I think it's pretty clear that this is unlikely to be successful.  My suggestion for these students is that they **should** vocalise what they are reading.  To take an extreme and admittedly made-up example, if someone reads
$$\{\,z\in{\Bbb C}\mid z=\overline z\,\}$$
as "squiggle-$z$-funny-sort-of-e-C-with-an-extra-line-on-it-vertical-line-$z$-three-horizontal-lines-with-another-$z$-under-one-of-them-final-squiggle" then their chances of success in mathematics are vanishingly small.

Hope this helps!  BTW I have never actually used the term "vocalise" with my students, but it's a good one so I might steal it ;-)

Comment: Hm. I found that 'Zed is an element of C such that zed equals zed (don't know what that overscore means)' requires me to find some visual analogue of it. So my thoughts usually proceed, 'z is just a variable, so z, element of C - ::draw a circle for C in my head, put z inside it::, such that ::draw a circle around C representing attendant circumstances - put a note to self in there that z=z overscore. Then work with the set C and whatever else and check to make sure they don't violate the attendant circumstances. I don't know if that's an effective way to do it.

Comment: I certainly didn't mean to suggest you don't use visual images - sorry if it came across that way - they are indeed very important.  I suspect that most mathematicians think both visually and verbally, with the balance different for different people.  BTW $\overline z$ is read as "$z$ conjugate" and it is indeed a good thing to visualise, see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexConjugate.html) if you want to know what it means.

Comment: You didn't suggest it. I just meant to say "Here's what I'm doing - what do you think?"

Comment: I think what you are doing is good, but I wouldn't totally neglect the other approach.  It may not give you much but I feel fairly sure it will give you something.

Comment: There is something a bit similar to what you are describing in Richard Feynman's memoirs *Surely You're Joking, Mr Feynman!*, in the chapter entitled "A Different Box of Tools".  I haven't checked but you can probably find it online.

Comment: You mean to vocalise it? (I agree - 'really getting it' seems paramount).